# Elastic search many index search

Tags: logstash

I have log file parsed using logstash and send it to the elastic search server. Data send to elastic server looks like below.

```
"@version" => "1",
timestamp" => "2015-06-18T11:26:12.411Z",
"type" => "log",
"host" => "Raj",
"login" => "raj@gmail.com",
"IP" => "127.0.0.1",
 "RequestID" => "sdfD1dsdfdee",
```

Now, if I see the index created in elastic server by the name `"logstash-2015.06.18"` and if push the same kind data with different time stamp tomorrow this will create another index like `"logstash-2015.06.19"`. Now, I wanted to get all the logged in time by the login called "raj@gmail.com". How can I get that?

I can not always try http://localhost:9200/logstash-2015.06.19/_search
something like this because in real time I may not know the index name created by default , Also how can I get consolidated result of two index which is created today and tomorrow?

I tried following  using head plugin and this gives me all the results not only matched results also I tried query_string both did not work.

http://localhost:9200/_search

```
{ "query": {"term": {"login": "raj@gmail.com"   }  }}}
```

Please give your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[The doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) says you can search across all indices:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/tweet/_search?q=tag:wow'
```

or all indices and types:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=tag:wow'
```

Comment: Yes, if i hit the http://localhost:9200/_search?q=tag:wow url it works. But Since i am working on windows and i cant do the curl hence i am looking for the query in head plugin of elastic search.